# JHipster CustomParameterizedException and Angular message

Tags: spring, angular, exception, jhipster

I'm using JHipster v.4.9.0. There is CustomParameterizedException where we can put message and params.

```
 Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
 params.put("foo", "foo_value");
 params.put("bar", "bar_value");
 throw new CustomParameterizedException("error.customError", params);
```

Can I use this parameters somehow in gateway in Angular? Someone knows what is the purpose of them?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a lot of testing I found out that backend returned like that using jhipster exception:

```
 Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
 params.put("foo", "foo_value");
 params.put("bar", "bar_value");
 throw new CustomParameterizedException("error.customError", params);
```

and frontend error.customError have to be defined like that in error.json file:

```
"customError": "It shows with params bar: {{ bar }} , foo: {{ foo }}"
```

{{ bar }} will be replaced with value bar_value and massage will be:

```
It shows with params bar: bar_value , foo: foo_value
```